# How to get a wallet address and set label via RPC?

Tags: wallet, bitcoind, address, json-rpc, address-generation

I'm familiar with the basic RPC commands, but I'm having trouble retrieving/adding an address to a wallet, using purely RPC calls (i.e. bitcoind only, not bitcoin-qt).

My understanding is that addresses are associated with accounts, but I'm unsure what role "accounts" play, and how to create new ones etc.

In pseudocode, this is what I want to be able to do:

```
if (count(getAddressesByLabel("donations")) == 0) {
    address = wallet.createBitcoinAddress();
    address.setLabel("donations");
}

donationAddress = getAddressesByLabel("donations"))
```

Comment: Don't build your accounting system on `accounts`. Accounts are more of a legacy feature, their future is uncertain, they are vulnerable to hardware failures and as such using them directly for accounting third party funds is a really bad idea.

Comment: @GeorgeKimionis - do you have any documentation for those changes and views? Surely labels are backed up with the wallet?

Comment: Labels are backed up along with their corresponding addresses. Please take a look at: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/issues/3816.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may have already read this, but make sure you read this if you want to know about how the accounts feature of the core client works: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Accounts_explained. (It's somewhat of a legacy feature.)

Are you looking to be able to do this manually with the RPC methods, or automated?

For manually, do:

```
bitcoin-cli getaddressesbyaccount "donations"
```

If the JSON array returned is empty, then no address is associated. To create a new bitcoin address with that label, do:

```
bitcoin-cli getnewaddress "donations"
```

To get an address for the "donations" account, do:

```
bitcoin-cli getaccountaddress "donations"
```

Comment: `bitcoin-cli getaccountaddress "..."` has been deprecated. It would be nice if this answer were updated